# Export R object table to excel

Tags: r

I am searching for a way to export table-like R objects to excel/csv. for example the gains table, in R it is saved as an object. The usual write.table function doesn't allow me to convert the object to csv. although the object is like a table...:

> gains(actual, predicted, groups=10,optimal=FALSE,percents=FALSE)->gains_test2

```
> dput(head(gains_test2))

structure(list(depth = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 
100), obs = c(146L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 146L, 147L, 147L, 
147L, 147L), cume.obs = c(146L, 293L, 440L, 587L, 734L, 880L, 
1027L, 1174L, 1321L, 1468L), mean.resp = c(0.0116469582940705, 
0.0125322442801302, 0.0142252481339337, 0.0106531565074638, 0.0130847548479835, 
0.0106034244135535, 0.00455378455081303, 0.0061834241946857, 
0.00989105136990672, 0.00841145735618072), cume.mean.resp = c(0.0116469582940705, 
0.012091112014039, 0.0128041074904584, 0.0122654536667783, 0.012429537145848, 
0.0121265684425355, 0.0110426354025324, 0.0104341992461836, 0.010373758112336, 
0.0101772606932932), cume.pct.of.total = c(0.113817337305101, 
0.237124763149948, 0.377090015198269, 0.481908695451763, 0.610652390679108, 
0.714272022740551, 0.759077680710614, 0.819917710900762, 0.917237876073098, 
1)), .Names = c("depth", "obs", "cume.obs", "mean.resp", "cume.mean.resp", 
"cume.pct.of.total")) 


> print(gains_test2)
Depth                           Cume    Cume Pct                     Mean
of          Cume     Mean      Mean    of Total    Lift   Cume     Model
File    N      N      Resp      Resp      Resp     Index   Lift     Score
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10   146    146      0.01      0.01     11.38 %     114    114      0.02 
 20   147    293      0.01      0.01     23.71 %     123    119      0.01 
 30   147    440      0.01      0.01     37.71 %     140    126      0.01 
 40   147    587      0.01      0.01     48.19 %     105    121      0.01 
 50   147    734      0.01      0.01     61.07 %     129    122      0.01 
 60   146    880      0.01      0.01     71.43 %     104    119      0.01 
 70   147   1027      0.00      0.01     75.91 %      45    109      0.01 
 80   147   1174      0.01      0.01     81.99 %      61    103      0.01 
 90   147   1321      0.01      0.01     91.72 %      97    102      0.01 
100   147   1468      0.01      0.01    100.00 %      83    100      0.01


> as.data.frame(gains_test2)
Error in as.data.frame.default(gains_test2) : 
  cannot coerce class '"gains"' into a data.frame
```

any idea? thanks!

========================================================================

Comment: Have you checked out `?write.csv` by any chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of Intro to R.

Comment: If I really have to move data into Excel, I use the 'RODBC' package and the 'sqlSave' function or else I use RExcel (http://www.statconn.com/products.html).

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the package? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gains/gains.pdf It looks to me like the print.gains function might output the table you want, then you could use `write.csv` to export to Excel. I would check it out, but I do not want to install the package.

Comment: @DWin sorry..just edited the post with output. and no write.matrix does not work as this is an object, not data.frame..i tried to convert it to data.frame but failed.

Comment: @ialm yes. does not work..this is an object, not a dataset.

Comment: @dayne unfortunately print.gains dost not work. the output is as my post above. print.gains only print the output in R as an object. and write.csv does not work as R cannot  coerce "gains"into a data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a dataframe, but it was pretty easy to turn it into one.

```
dat <- as.data.frame(structure(list(depth = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80,
90,  100), obs = c(146L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 147L, 146L, 147L, 147L, 
147L, 147L), cume.obs = c(146L, 293L, 440L, 587L, 734L, 880L, 
1027L, 1174L, 1321L, 1468L), mean.resp = c(0.0116469582940705, 
0.0125322442801302, 0.0142252481339337, 0.0106531565074638, 0.0130847548479835, 
0.0106034244135535, 0.00455378455081303, 0.0061834241946857, 
0.00989105136990672, 0.00841145735618072), cume.mean.resp = c(0.0116469582940705, 
0.012091112014039, 0.0128041074904584, 0.0122654536667783, 0.012429537145848, 
0.0121265684425355, 0.0110426354025324, 0.0104341992461836, 0.010373758112336, 
0.0101772606932932), cume.pct.of.total = c(0.113817337305101, 
0.237124763149948, 0.377090015198269, 0.481908695451763, 0.610652390679108, 
0.714272022740551, 0.759077680710614, 0.819917710900762, 0.917237876073098, 
1)), .Names = c("depth", "obs", "cume.obs", "mean.resp", "cume.mean.resp", 
"cume.pct.of.total")) )
write.csv(dat, file="test.csv")
```

Apparent success. (Most R-people would say that both atomic and recursive vectors with and without attributes, an umbrella that now includes lists, dataframes, matrices, arrays, ordinary vectors, and factors, are all "objects".)

I cannot tell if the original `gains_test2` object had something more besides the lists that were in the structure object. The print method for gain-classed objects seems to add extra information, perhaps that was not in the first six lists returned by `head`. I would have thought that if it were more irregular that there would have been more attributes, but perhaps those complexities are in the 7th or higher lists of a gains-object.

You may find that you can extract the first 10 lists with `head(gains_test2, 10)` and convert to a dataframe. I will admit that I sometimes do my export to Excel by just screen-scraping the R console output and using the Data/Text to Columns... dialog. There is also the `capture.console` function if you end up wanteing the otuput of `print`-ed object and find that the object's structure is not what you see on the console.

Comment: Thanks! sorry.. first time trying to turn an object to data.frame.